# Is there any Javascript library for Image processing

Tags: javascript, image-processing

Are there any JavaScript libraries for image processing like:

- Color corrections
- Combining two or more images
- Image recognition etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.pixastic.com/ tends to work well. Also, if you want high performance, you can use shader in WebGL.

Comment: Can we compare two images using these libraries?

Comment: What do you mean by comparing images?

Comment: I think he means, comparing images for identical or similar images.

Answer (score 1):

There is a port of Processing to JavaScript: [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org)

Comment: Unfortunately, the site seems to be down currently. To see the library's capabilities, take a look at some demos at: http://ejohn.org/apps/processing.js/examples/basic/